# I really am thinking of covering my pipes underneath my kitchen sink and then removing all the cabinets there. They are rotten / causing gnats BAD

Tags: kitchens, old-pipes

I rent but landlord will not spend money to really fix ANY issues. He likes “bandaid” repairs. I’m at a loss! I really cannot cook in a kitchen full of gnats/ fruit flies

Comment: Cannot really help without pictures, but maybe this is more a health department matter.  Most places have rules on how landlords must upkeep their places.

Comment: We might be able to help you get rid of the bugs, etc. if we had more details about the current conditions. The bugs need something to eat (and drink) they could be coming out of the plumbing or under/behind the cabinets. You could maybe fix this without tearing up the kitchen or spending much money...if you can take away their food and water they won't last long. Please post some pictures of the plumbing, the cabinets, the bugs, etc. Add some details to your question because, as it is, it's likely to be closed/removed for lack of detail.

Comment: What are the insects doing for water? It sounds like you have leaks there. Leaks are a serious problem for landlords because they destroy the building.  Be a squeaky wheel and bother the landlord until they are fixed.  They'd have to be a fool to not fix them.

Comment: Fruit flies, in my experience, have less to do with the cabinets than with there being food available for them to lay eggs next to... and once they're present they can be a pain to knock down again except by setting up glue traps (flypaper works, window-mounted sticky surfaces work better), taking kitchen trash out immediately for a while, using a well covered kitchen trash can (and periodically cleaning it if you see larvae on the inside of the lid), and in the worst cases waving a vacuum around the kitchen trying to grab the ones you can see (which may work better than a flyswatter).

Comment: I don’t know how to post pictures:( but we have covered all the drain holes in the kitchen and bathroom. We have a covered trash can and don’t let dishes sit. The landlord literally doesn’t care- at all. I have done everything other than call the county inspector- he says that is why rent is cheaper than most. We have too many people and a pit bull/ service dog to make it easy to move. There’s no active water leaks but we personally bought 50$ worth of spray foam and sprayed everything we could find. We still have gnats/ fruit flies both. I don’t mean a few either

Comment: And my landlord knows and has known

Comment: Even though this has been closed, you can still [edit] the question, then click the "sun & mountain" icon above the text edit box. Drag & drop images in, or click "browse" and select them from your pictures (phone or desktop).

Comment: Mixup Muphy's oil soap and orange juice, 1:4 and leave a glass out for the fruit flys. They are attracted to the OJ, so they drink it, then the oil soap quickly kills them. You can also make a batch of watered down oil soap (25%) in a sprayer or old spray cleaner bottle. The mix will blast flies right out of the air, literally dead before they hit the floor. It's entertaining, satisfying, and safe for pets and humans.

Answer (score 3):

Alert your landlord.  Document your issues AND the emails or letters you send to the landlord. Take a lot of pictures. Show the insects in the pics if possible. Give him/her a reasonable time to correct the problem. Let the LL know if you see no action you are going to file a report with the health department.  You MUST document your communication with dates and times if possible. If you remove cabinets the landlord can argue that you have caused the problem.  Be aware that if this goes to the health department, they may find the home uninhabitable and you will have to move.

Comment: Also, be aware that if you go the the health department and they force the landlord to fix things, he might be rather angry that you've forced him to spend money. Expect that your rent might increase significantly and/or he may make your life miserable in other ways. Unfortunately, some people aren't nice and aren't interested in doing the right thing.